# jquery - best way of finding if select box option is unselected

Tags: jquery

Whats the best way to check a select box to find out if the selected options value is empty?

i have tried the following and other variations but no luck so far:

```
if($('.mySelectBox').val('').length) { alert('not selected'); }
```

Comment: Probably because with select boxes, most of the time (always?) the first option is preselected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ($('.mySelectBox :selected').size() == 0) {
       alert('not selected');
}
```

This selects the set of options in `.mySelectBox` that are selected, and counts them.

Here's a live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/RTecb/

Comment: The first option will be selected, so this really doesn't work :)

Comment: Depends on whether this is a dropdown or a select box, but good point :)

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
if(!$('.mySelectBox').val()) { 
  alert('not selected'); 
}
```

This alerts if the selected option has an empty value, e.g.:

```
<option value="">Please Select</option>
```

A suggestion though, if the box is unique, use an ID (this only checks the *first* `class="mySelectBox"`, you'll need a loop if you want to check more than one).

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `val` with an argument, that means it tries to set the value instead of getting the value. Try this instead:

```
if ($('.mySelectBox').val()) { alert('not selected'); }
```